# How do I replace/filter out "$\n (quote end-of-line newline) using grep, awk, and sed in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a Java project that has many lines that look like this:

```
myMethod("some text here ..."
+ " ... more text here"
+ " ... and even more text here");
```

I need to perform a bash search for this:

```
"some text here ... ... more text here ... and even more text here";
```

I have tried things like this:

```
# Filtering for text between the two parenthesis
$ grep -rn "myMethod" . | awk -F\( '{print $2}' | awk -F\) '{print $1}' | sort | uniq

# replacing the `"$\n` with nothing
$ grep -rn "myMethod" . | sed -e 's/"$\n\s//g' | sort | uniq

# same
$ grep -rn "myMethod" . | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/"$\n/,/g' | sort | uniq
```

However, none of these is giving me what I want, which is all of the unique Strings being passed into the myMethod method.

So, how can I go about replacing or filtering out `"$\n` (quote end-of-line newline) using grep, awk, and sed in bash?

Comment: Could you please provide sample of expected output in your post and let us know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I did when I said 'I need to perform a bash search for this:

"some text here ... ... more text here ... and even more text here";' Essentially, the text between the two parenthesis.

Comment: By seeing your profile came to know that you hardly select any answer as correct answer, give it sometime and when you see few answers to your post, try to select any answer(which is best suited to your question) as correct one. You could do it for your previous asked questions too(whever applicable), thanks.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 If you would bother to look further, you would see that I very often select an answer as the correct answer. I cannot do this, however, if no answer is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes true, that is why I mentioned wherever it is applicable, no worries. Keep sharing and learning on SO, cheers.

Comment: You used `.`, does that mean you have many files have this `myMethod` block you need to search?

Comment: @Tiw Yes ... I am recursively searching through multiple directories for classes using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (`GNU grep` and `GNU sed`, I believe you are using them):

```
$ cat file
myMethod("some text here ..."
+ " ... more text here"
+ " ... and even more text here");

$ grep -rzn "myMethod" . | sed -rn '/myMethod/{:a;s/\)//;tb;N;ba;:b;s/\n//g;s/[^"]*$//;:c;s/^[^"]*"([^"]*)"(.*)/\2\1/;tc;p;}'
some text here ... ... more text here ... and even more text here

$ grep -rzn "myMethod" . | sed -rn '/myMethod/{:a;s/\)//;tb;N;ba;:b;s/\n//g;s/[^"]*$//;:c;s/^[^"]*"([^"]*)"(.*)/\2\1/;tc;s/^/"/;s/$/";/;p}'
"some text here ... ... more text here ... and even more text here";
```

I believe it will work on multiple files and multiple occurrences.
I used `sed` to read after lines until it finds close paren `)` and then concatenate.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do (using GNU sed for `-z` and recognition of `\n`)?

```
$ sed -z 's/"\n+ "//g' file
myMethod("some text here ... ... more text here ... and even more text here");

$ sed -z 's/"\n+ "//g' file | sed -n 's/^myMethod("\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'
some text here ... ... more text here ... and even more text here
```

If the string being passed to myMethod can contain escaped `"`s then you'd just need to tell us how they're escaped (doubled? backslashed? something else?) and then they'd be easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

try if this works for you:

```
awk -F'"' '/^myMethod\(/,/\);$/{str = str " " $2}END{print str}' file
```

For your input, this will yield " some text here ...  ... more text here  ... and even more text here". you can fix the leading space easily if needed.

Basically use the range pattern: search only between string `myMethod(` and the end of function call `);` and then grab and concatenate `$2`. This will not work if multiple function arguments on the same line though. you might also need to consider the white spaces before `myMethod(` and after `);`.

Answer (score 0):

something that works exactly on your provided strings and formatting (quotes and "+" symbols included) would look like this:

```
>cat my_file.txt
myMethod("some text here ..."
+ " ... more text here ..."
+ " ... and even more text here");
other lines
and some other");

>sed -n '/myMethod/,/");/p' my_file.txt | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' -e "s/\"//g" -e "s/\+//g" -e "s/myMethod//g"
(some text here ...   ... more text here ...   ... and even more text here);
```

first sed extracts everything between string [myMethod] and first occurrence of string [");]

then we have another sed and first expression eliminates all newlines character, second expression eliminates the double quotes, 3rd expression eliminates the "+" symbols and finally the last expression removes the "myMethod" string from final output

if you want this absurdly done, you can add [-e "s/[()]/\"/g"] to transform the leading and ending parentheses () of output, into double quotes "

L.E: this will obviously mess up with your code if you have any of the following characters inside you code: [+"()myMethod]

Comment: I tried `grep -rn "myMethod" | xargs -i sed -n '/myMethod/,/");/p' {} | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' -e "s/\"//g" -e "s/\+//g" -e "s/myMethod//g"` but it didn't work.

Comment: but you're executing `grep -rn "myMethod"` at beginning of command and this is input for the xargs after the pipe. what is the reason for this `grep`? What are you applying the `grep` on. You need an input file to it.

Comment: I am using `grep` to find all classes within my project structure that use `myMethod` and then removing the `"$\n` so that I can get the entire method call on one single line.

Comment: so you want to change `ALL` your files in-situ, re-writing the method as a single line.
you  only mentioned you want content of your method brought on the screen as a single line. or maybe i misunderstood ...

Answer (score 0):

No need for other tools; this can be done with bash alone.

```
$ s=$'myMethod("some text here ..."\n+ " ... more text here"\n+ " ... and even more text here");'
$ echo "$s"
myMethod("some text here ..."
+ " ... more text here"
+ " ... and even more text here");
$ t="${s//$'\n'/ }"
$ t="${t//\" + \"/ }"
$ t="${t#myMethod(\"}"
$ t="${t%\");}"
$ echo "$t"
some text here ...  ... more text here  ... and even more text here
```

This uses a bash feature called "pattern substitution" which is part of "Parameter Expansion" which you can read about on bash's man page or the official [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: I just used those String fragments (e.g., "some text here ...") as an example. The text is supposed to be whatever is in the method parameter. It could be any text.

Comment: @Brian, your question asked how to do this in bash, so I provided a bash solution. How you get multiline text into a source variable is up to you. :)  You can of course use pattern substitution to remove *any* text that appears in your source variable, including `myMethod("`.

Comment: @Brian .. okay, I've updated my example to include some extra trimming of your source data. Do read up on Parameter Expansion.

Answer (score 0):

This will go (locally in current dir) through all the files that have string `myMethod` in them, reading the method until enclosing signal `);` and replacing it with a one liner:

```
>>cat my_file.txt
random first line
random second line

myMethod(first line of code
second line of code
third line of code);
# notice above method ending in string ");". This is important to mark the enclosing of the method.
# this string should not be present anywhere else withing the content of the method

other lines
and some other");
```

```
>>cat other_file.txt
myMethod("text in other file ..."
+ " ... yet more text from other file ..."
+ " ... and even more text here from the second file"); # ending of method
other lines
and some other");
```

```
ACTUAL COMAND
>>for file_containing_myMethod in `grep -l "myMethod" *`; do ONE_LINER=`sed -n '/myMethod/,/);/p' ${file_containing_myMethod} | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`; sed -i "/myMethod/,/);/{/);/ s/.*/${ONE_LINER}/; t; d}" ${file_containing_myMethod}; done
random first line
random second line

myMethod(first line of code second line of code third line of code);
# notice above method ending in string ");". This is important to mark the enclosing of the method.
# this string should not be present anywhere else within the content of the method

other lines
and some other");

myMethod("text in other file ..." + " ... yet more text from other file ..." + " ... and even more text here from the second file"); # ending of method
other lines
and some other");
```

Please note that when you test you should eliminate the `-i` flag from the last `sed`. `-i` will change/rewrite your files instantly, and you don't want that before testing.